# Determining JavaScript Post Size

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339241/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-a-http-post-transaction-to-be-submitted) was asked by someone else, but no decent answer was given. Let *me* help by explaining my particular situation so there is no mixup that I am using AJAX at the moment (I am ***NOT*** for the sake of this question, but I may switch someday)...

I am submitting a form via a regular HTML  to PHP submit using POST, which, in my case, has a lot of text, sometimes enough to exceed the POST limit. Is there a way via JavaScript to calculate if the POST will be too big before it's submitted? If there's no easy way to automatically determine the server's POST limit, I can handle that manually, but I need to calculate the bytes to be sent and stop it (and send back a warning message) that it will not calculate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think POST has a limit at all... maybe the limit is inflicted by the server (PHP)?

Comment: @FelixKling there should be some limit ... no ? ( not by the iis)

Comment: `POST` has a limit, though it is far larger than `GET`.

Comment: I'm not sure why there is any confusion about this. The `POST` limit is set by the server. Your browser might also have a limit but I suspect it's far higher (couple of MB/GB?)

Comment: Well, it's even in the question... I have not read it thoroughly... never mind, ignore my comment please. @RoyiNamir: Deleted my second comment since Frits already said the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy to determine the size of the `POST` request so long as it's just text input. If you also have file inputs it'll be a bit harder but doable with HTML5 stuff.

Just add up all the fields and their values.

Typically `POST` form-data looks like:

`"key=value&key2=value"`

So add 1 byte for each field (for the `=`), and n-1 bytes in total (for the `&`).

Then get a good number for the header, 100 bytes or so? Maybe 200.

Comment: Still not sure I understand how I'm supposed to do this via JavaScript before submitting the data? This is NOT AFTER I have sent the information.